# Text-based C++ video game

Tags: c++, role-playing-game

Please critique this and make suggestions on the best practices.

```
//Seasons Divided
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
string Answer;

//Character Declarations
string Sex;
string Age;
string Height;
string HairLength;
string HairColor;
string EyeColor;
string Ethnicity;

system ("title Seasons Divided");
system ("mode 1000");
system ("color 4f");

cout << "\t\t\t\tFBI Notice:\n";
cout << "\tAll rights reserved. This game or any portion thereof\n";
cout << "\tmay not be reproduced or used in any manner whatsoever\n";
cout << "\twithout the express written permission of the publisher\n";
cout << "\texcept for the use of brief quotations in a review.\n";
cout << "\tPirating of this game is investigated by the FBI and is\n";
cout << "\tconsidered plagiarism and is a federal crime and will be\n";
cout << "\theld as a federal offense in court. It can be punishable\n";
cout << "\tby fines up to $250,000 and up to 10 years in a federal prison\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t";

system ("pause");
system ("cls");
system ("color 0f");

cout << "CAUTION!\n\n";
cout << "The adventure you are about to embark contains high levels of:\n";
cout << "Fun\n";
cout << "Adventure\n";
cout << "Excitement\n\n\n";
cout << "If you have a record of buzz killing or anything similar, \nthen this game is NOT for you.\n\n";
cout << "IMPORTANT: Game is best played in full screen mode.\n\n\n\n\n";

system ("pause");
system ("cls");

cout << "\tT";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTe";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew ";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew I";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew In";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Ind";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Indu";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Indus";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Indust";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industr";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industri";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industrie";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries ";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries P";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries Pr";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries Pre";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries Pres";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries Prese";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries Presen";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries Present";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew Industries Presents\n";
_sleep(5000);

system ("color 0b");
do 
{
system ("cls");
cout << " @@@@@@   @@@@@@@@   @@@@@@    @@@@@@    @@@@@@   @@@  @@@   @@@@@@      @@@@@@@   @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@\n";
cout << "@@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@ @@@  @@@@@@@      @@@@@@@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  \n";
cout << "!@@       @@!       @@!  @@@  !@@       @@!  @@@  @@!@!@@@  !@@          @@!  @@@  @@!  @@!  @@@  @@!  @@!  @@@  @@!       @@!  @@@  \n";
cout << "!@!       !@!       !@!  @!@  !@!       !@!  @!@  !@!!@!@!  !@!          !@!  @!@  !@!  !@!  @!@  !@!  !@!  @!@  !@!       !@!  @!@  \n";
cout << "!!@@!!    @!!!:!    @!@!@!@!  !!@@!!    @!@  !@!  @!@ !!@!  !!@@!!       @!@  !@!  !!@  @!@  !@!  !!@  @!@  !@!  @!!!:!    @!@  !@!  \n";
cout << " !!@!!!   !!!!!:    !!!@!!!!   !!@!!!   !@!  !!!  !@!  !!!   !!@!!!      !@!  !!!  !!!  !@!  !!!  !!!  !@!  !!!  !!!!!:    !@!  !!!  \n";
cout << "     !:!  !!:       !!:  !!!       !:!  !!:  !!!  !!:  !!!       !:!     !!:  !!!  !!:  :!:  !!:  !!:  !!:  !!!  !!:       !!:  !!!  \n";
cout << "    !:!   :!:       :!:  !:!      !:!   :!:  !:!  :!:  !:!      !:!      :!:  !:!  :!:   ::!!:!   :!:  :!:  !:!  :!:       :!:  !:!  \n";
cout << ":::: ::    :: ::::  ::   :::  :::: ::   ::::: ::   ::   ::  :::: ::       :::: ::   ::    ::::     ::   :::: ::   :: ::::   :::: ::  \n";
cout << ":: : :    : :: ::    :   : :  :: : :     : :  :   ::    :   :: : :       :: :  :   :       :      :    :: :  :   : :: ::   :: :  :   \n";
cout << "\n\nPress Q to continue: ";
cin >> Answer;
}while (Answer != "Q" && Answer != "q");

CharacterCustomization://I know this is looked down upon for "Spaghetti Code", but I feel this is appropriate in this case
system ("cls");
system ("color 0f");

cout << "Your alarm clock blares in your ears. As you open your eyes, you shut the alarm clock off and get out of bed.\n";
cout << "You walk to the bathroom and push open the door. It opens without fault and you feel warm steam brush against\n";
cout << "your skin. You turn towards the mirror and it is covered with fog. You brush your teeth and wipe down the\n";
cout << "mirror. You see yourself in the mirror...\n\n\n";
_sleep(15000);
do
{
    cout << "Are you a Boy or a Girl? ";
    cin >> Sex;
}
while (Sex != "Boy" && Sex != "Girl" && Sex != "boy" && Sex != "girl");
do
{
    cout << "Are you Black or White? ";
    cin >> Ethnicity;
}
while (Ethnicity != "White" && Ethnicity != "white" && Ethnicity != "Black" && "black");
do
{
    cout << "What color are your eyes? ";
    cin >> EyeColor;
}
while (EyeColor != "Blue" && EyeColor != "blue" && EyeColor != "Brown" && EyeColor != "brown" && EyeColor != "Green" && EyeColor != "green" && EyeColor != "Black" && EyeColor != "black" && EyeColor != "White" && EyeColor != "white" && EyeColor != "Gray" && EyeColor != "gray" && EyeColor != "Red" && EyeColor != "red");
do
{
    cout << "Is your hair Long or Short? ";
    cin >> HairLength;
}
while (HairLength != "Long" && HairLength != "long" && HairLength != "Short" && HairLength != "short");
do
{
    cout << "What color is your hair? ";
    cin >> HairColor;
}
while (HairColor != "Black" && HairColor != "black" && HairColor != "Brown" && HairColor != "brown" && HairColor != "Blonde" && HairColor != "blonde" && HairColor != "Blond" && HairColor != "blond" && HairColor != "White" && HairColor != "white" && HairColor != "Gray" && HairColor != "gray");
do
{
    cout << "Are you Old, Middle, or Young Aged? ";
    cin >> Age;
}
while (Age != "Old" && Age != "old" && Age != "Middle" && Age!= "middle" && Age != "Young" && Age != "young");
_sleep(1000);

cout << "So you're a " << Ethnicity << ' ' << Sex << " with " << EyeColor << " eyes and " << HairLength << ' ' << HairColor << " hair? ";
CharacterCustomizationInput:
cin >> Answer;
if (Answer != "Yes" && Answer != "yes" && Answer != "No" && Answer != "no")
{
    cout << "Invalid Input";
    goto CharacterCustomizationInput;
}if (Answer == "No" || Answer == "no"){
    goto CharacterCustomization;//Again... I feel it is appropriate in this case for lack of any alternative
}
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up [ncurses](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses). It is a platform/terminal independent library for moving around a screen (terminal). Thus allowing you to draw text around the screen without resorting to system specific commands like `cls`

Comment: Why does this have a lot of down votes? It looks like a normal code review post.

Answer (score 4):

I see a number of simple things that you could do to improve this.

## Structure Your Data

You have several attributes for the player - `Age`, `Sex`, `Height`, etc. Each of these is stored as a stand-alone `string`. You should create a `struct` or `class` that holds this data. Something like this:

```
struct Player {
    string Sex;
    string Age;
    string Height;
    // ...etc.
};
```

If you do the above, then you can have other non-player characters that have the same attributes as the player. Just create another instance of the `struct` with the settings you want.

I'd also recommend using the proper type for each data member. For example, as you have it now, you allow a `string` for `Sex`, but only accept 2 different values. This should be an enum:

```
typedef enum {
    MALE = 0,
    FEMALE
} Gender;
```

And the data member should be declared like this:

```
struct Player {
    Gender Sex;
    Generation Age;
    // ... etc. ...
};
```

(And I'd also caution you that things like gender and ethnicity are not binary choices. You may limit your audience by making such assumptions.)

## Use Functions

It's not really a good idea to put so much code into your `main()` function. You really should create a different function for each task that your program performs. For example, you print various items for the player to read, then print the instructions, and then ask the player for input. Each of those should be in its own function. Something like this:

```
void displayNotice()
{
    system ("color 4f");
    
    cout << "\t\t\t\tFBI Notice:\n";
    cout << "\tAll rights reserved. This game or any portion thereof\n";
    cout << "\tmay not be reproduced or used in any manner whatsoever\n";
    cout << "\twithout the express written permission of the publisher\n";
    cout << "\texcept for the use of brief quotations in a review.\n";
    cout << "\tPirating of this game is investigated by the FBI and is\n";
    cout << "\tconsidered plagiarism and is a federal crime and will be\n";
    cout << "\theld as a federal offense in court. It can be punishable\n";
    cout << "\tby fines up to $250,000 and up to 10 years in a federal prison\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t";
    system ("pause");
}

void displayWarning()
{
    system ("cls");
    system ("color 0f");
    cout << "CAUTION!\n\n";
    cout << "The adventure you are about to embark contains high levels of:\n";
    cout << "Fun\n";
    cout << "Adventure\n";
    cout << "Excitement\n\n\n";
    cout << "If you have a record of buzz killing or anything similar, \nthen this game is NOT for you.\n\n";
    cout << "IMPORTANT: Game is best played in full screen mode.\n\n\n\n\n";
}

// ... etc.
```

Then your `main()` function would look something like this:

```
int main (void)
{
    Player player;

    system ("title Seasons Divided");
    system ("mode 1000");

    displayNotice();
    system ("pause");
    
    displayWarning();
    system ("pause");
    
    // ... etc. ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Redundant character case comparisons

```
while (EyeColor != "Blue" && EyeColor != "blue" && EyeColor != "Brown" && EyeColor != "brown" && EyeColor != "Green" && EyeColor != "green" && EyeColor != "Black" && EyeColor != "black" && EyeColor != "White" && EyeColor != "white" && EyeColor != "Gray" && EyeColor != "gray" && EyeColor != "Red" && EyeColor != "red");
```

You could simply use [`toupper` and `tolower`](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284392&answer=1046053421)...

```
while( 
    std::toupper(EyeColor) != std::toupper("BLUE") &&
    std::toupper(EyeColor) != std::toupper("GREEN") &&
    // etc.
)
```

---

#### Large ASCII art in inline script

This:

```
cout << " @@@@@@   @@@@@@@@   @@@@@@    @@@@@@    @@@@@@   @@@  @@@   @@@@@@      @@@@@@@   @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@\n";
cout << "@@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@ @@@  @@@@@@@      @@@@@@@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  \n";
cout << "!@@       @@!       @@!  @@@  !@@       @@!  @@@  @@!@!@@@  !@@          @@!  @@@  @@!  @@!  @@@  @@!  @@!  @@@  @@!       @@!  @@@  \n";
cout << "!@!       !@!       !@!  @!@  !@!       !@!  @!@  !@!!@!@!  !@!          !@!  @!@  !@!  !@!  @!@  !@!  !@!  @!@  !@!       !@!  @!@  \n";
cout << "!!@@!!    @!!!:!    @!@!@!@!  !!@@!!    @!@  !@!  @!@ !!@!  !!@@!!       @!@  !@!  !!@  @!@  !@!  !!@  @!@  !@!  @!!!:!    @!@  !@!  \n";
cout << " !!@!!!   !!!!!:    !!!@!!!!   !!@!!!   !@!  !!!  !@!  !!!   !!@!!!      !@!  !!!  !!!  !@!  !!!  !!!  !@!  !!!  !!!!!:    !@!  !!!  \n";
cout << "     !:!  !!:       !!:  !!!       !:!  !!:  !!!  !!:  !!!       !:!     !!:  !!!  !!:  :!:  !!:  !!:  !!:  !!!  !!:       !!:  !!!  \n";
cout << "    !:!   :!:       :!:  !:!      !:!   :!:  !:!  :!:  !:!      !:!      :!:  !:!  :!:   ::!!:!   :!:  :!:  !:!  :!:       :!:  !:!  \n";
cout << ":::: ::    :: ::::  ::   :::  :::: ::   ::::: ::   ::   ::  :::: ::       :::: ::   ::    ::::     ::   :::: ::   :: ::::   :::: ::  \n";
cout << ":: : :    : :: ::    :   : :  :: : :     : :  :   ::    :   :: : :       :: :  :   :       :      :    :: :  :   : :: ::   :: :  :   \n";
```

That shouldn't be in your `main` method. Obviously this is never going to change (until you decide to change your marketing plan) and would be more reusable if it were stored somewhere in a constant that you can just call when you need it. So just take that out of `main` and instead [do something like this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135862/3626537)

```
const char *SPLASH_SCREEN =
"  @@@@@@   @@@@@@@@   @@@@@@    @@@@@@    @@@@@@   @@@  @@@   @@@@@@      @@@@@@@   @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@\n; "
" @@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@  @@@@ @@@  @@@@@@@      @@@@@@@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  \n; "
" !@@       @@!       @@!  @@@  !@@       @@!  @@@  @@!@!@@@  !@@          @@!  @@@  @@!  @@!  @@@  @@!  @@!  @@@  @@!       @@!  @@@  \n; "
" !@!       !@!       !@!  @!@  !@!       !@!  @!@  !@!!@!@!  !@!          !@!  @!@  !@!  !@!  @!@  !@!  !@!  @!@  !@!       !@!  @!@  \n; "
" !!@@!!    @!!!:!    @!@!@!@!  !!@@!!    @!@  !@!  @!@ !!@!  !!@@!!       @!@  !@!  !!@  @!@  !@!  !!@  @!@  !@!  @!!!:!    @!@  !@!  \n; "
"  !!@!!!   !!!!!:    !!!@!!!!   !!@!!!   !@!  !!!  !@!  !!!   !!@!!!      !@!  !!!  !!!  !@!  !!!  !!!  !@!  !!!  !!!!!:    !@!  !!!  \n; "
"      !:!  !!:       !!:  !!!       !:!  !!:  !!!  !!:  !!!       !:!     !!:  !!!  !!:  :!:  !!:  !!:  !!:  !!!  !!:       !!:  !!!  \n; "
"     !:!   :!:       :!:  !:!      !:!   :!:  !:!  :!:  !:!      !:!      :!:  !:!  :!:   ::!!:!   :!:  :!:  !:!  :!:       :!:  !:!  \n; "
" :::: ::    :: ::::  ::   :::  :::: ::   ::::: ::   ::   ::  :::: ::       :::: ::   ::    ::::     ::   :::: ::   :: ::::   :::: ::  \n; "
" :: : :    : :: ::    :   : :  :: : :     : :  :   ::    :   :: : :       :: :  :   :       :      :    :: :  :   : :: ::   :: :  :   \n; "
```

Then you only need to retrieve it when you need it.

---

#### Forced waiting times while printing the publisher/developer

This whole section is not useful at all, and most would consider annoying at best:

```
cout << "\tT";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTe";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew ";
_sleep(100);
system ("cls");
cout << "\tTew I";
// etc.
```

Just get rid of the loop, output `cout << "\tTew Industries Presents\n";` once, and be done with it.